# javadoc not generated with jdk 1.9 but getting generated with jdk 1.8

Tags: java-8, javadoc, java-9

I am using same command to generate javadoc with jdk 1.8 and 1.9 while doc gets generated with errors and warning in jdk 1.8 but is not getting generated with 1.9.

Below is the command I am using:-

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin>javadoc -d D:\APIdoc -sourcepath D:\MyFile\src\main\java -subpackages com.abc.dap.pqr
Output:
100 errors 
100 warnings
Doc generated successfully

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9\bin>javadoc -d D:\APIdoc1 -sourcepath D:\MyFile\src\main\java -subpackages com.abc.dap.pqr
Output:
100 errors
Doc not generated

Below are the errors:-
error: package [package_name] does not exist
error: cannot find symbol
```

Same errors are observed in jdk1.8 and 1.9 but I am unable to understand why doc is not generated with 1.9.
Please suggest workaround for generating javadoc with jdk1.9

Comment: Maybe JDK 9 got stricter? Did you try fixing the errors (even if only by removing the offending files) and see what happens?

Comment: It's difficult to remove errors I have 1500+ classes and 100 packages and almost all classes have error.

Comment: Have you tried turning off some of the checks using `-Xdoclint:-<group>` or `-Xdoclint:none`? If that doesn't help, you can invoke the legacy javadoc tool with `-Xold`. See `javadoc -X` for more information.

Comment: @DavidConrad You should turn that into an answer.

Comment: @DavidConard -Xdoclint is not working, I want to generate the doc with 1.9 because it has search feature which is not present in 1.8 so I cannot use -Xold. Please suggest if there is any other way to do with 1.9

Comment: @DavidConard Thank you, -Xold is working, please ignore last comment

Comment: @SNEHALGUPTA With Java 9, could you share the complete error logs. Also, just for insight https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/whatsnew/toc.htm#JSNEW-GUID-DB9EB298-4944-4BF9-9CE0-B4A884F8294F should help you figure out what has changed in terms of generation. You might want to get into deep to learn about [taglet](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/221) and the [module system](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261) interpretation.

Comment: @SNEHALGUPTA, Repeated errors like "package does not exist" may indicate a systemic fault, such as a poorly configured command line. In general, try and use the same options for source path and class path as you would use for javac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have better luck by turning off some of the checks using `-Xdoclint:-<group>`, particularly `-Xdoclint:-reference` which will cause it to ignore issues relating to the references to Java API elements from Javadoc tags, or even `-Xdoclint:none` to turn off all checks. If that doesn't help, you can invoke the legacy javadoc tool with `-Xold`.

See `javadoc -X` or the [javadoc documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javadoc.htm) for more information.

Comment: In Java 10+ there is no more `-Xold` option. Is there any combination of new options which ignores errors, such as non-existing classes and packages in the source files I am trying to create javadocs for? The old tool reports the exact same errors and warnings, but still continues to generate HTML files, and the resulting Javadoc works perfectly fine, except for missing classes not being "clickable", of course.

Comment: @kriegaex I just tried it with JDK 17 and it still generates the HTML files, even though it reports some errors and warnings on the test I created. What version are you using?

Comment: I was using everything between 9 and 16 when I wrote my comment. Warnings would have been OK, but an error means that my Maven build fails. As far as I remember, the files were not generated in my case either, but I cannot remember 100%.

Answer (score 5):

It is a deliberate change in JDK 9 to treat the errors as unrecoverable and exit without generating the javadoc. This is documented in the JDK 9 release notes (http://jdk.java.net/9/release-notes#JDK-8175219).

As noted in the comments then the using the old doclet (with -Xold) might work for this case but it doesn't support module information. Also the old doclet will be removed in the next release.